# how to parse a file from a java docker container application

Tags: java, maven, docker, containers, spotify

I have a java application which needs to parse a data set file. I have containerized the app using docker but the container does not see my file in my host. 
So, I need to somehow include it inside the docker container or make it available through a docker volume which is mapped into my container.

inside the java app I have

```
String dataSet = "/usr/DataSet/TempData.txt"; // inside the container
File textfile = new File(dataSet);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(textfile);
```

and my file is stored in a directory (/home/myusername/Desktop/DataSet) in my host.

I compile and build my docker image using spotify plugin in maven.
After I build the image, I run a container and map a volume that contains my TempData.txt:

```
sudo docker run -it -v /home/myUserName/Desktop/DataSet:/usr/DataSet --name myapp myImageName bash
```

But I get java.io.FileNotFoundException error because the file is not available in my container ..

what is the best way to make a file available to my java dockerized app to be able to read and parse it ?

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: you map the file to `/usr/DataSet` but you search for the file in `/usr/TempData`.
Change one of them and it should work

Comment: Hi, Sorry it was a typo mistake .. Indeed I map to the same directory... I edited the post!

Comment: I tested the docker command in another Ubuntu dummy container. It creates the directory /usr/DataSet but no file is available in it !

Comment: Are you using Docker for Mac?

Comment: No, In Ubuntu.  But my problem is solved. I put the file in my home directory and then mapped it in to the container .. and now it works! Maybe volumes work in home directory only rather than other places .... It is still new for me and I need to discover more about it ... Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I put my file in my home directory. and then mapped it into my container ...